# java jooq merging 2 tables

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jooq

I'm struggle with 1 task. I have to merge 2 table by Id. So i create an object which contains 2 Strings and 1 array list of strings. Im using java spring boot. Then wrote an dao method with Jooq :

```java
public List<Data> getList() {
return create.select("table fields")
     .from(table_name)
     .join(table2).on(table.id.eq(table2.id))
     .fetchInto(Data.class)'
```

after mapping in service and making response in controller, i am getting error smth like that :

> org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from "table_field" (class java.lang.String) to interface java.util.List

Have tried to do a Map with `<String <List<Data>>` and grouped by one field, but this is the output that I am not really interested. Thanks for any answers!!

Comment: Do you really use "table fields" in the select or the real fields?

Comment: real fields ofcourse, just wanted give an example. I know that's a result is a HashMap. Thing is in sql after merge 2 tables i have 3 fields. I don't want to have multiple results, that's why i need a third field as a List<String>. I know that one of answer is to create a Map/Hashmap 1 key for multiple values, but kinda im struggle with that.

Comment: May I ask you to please update your example to one that more closely reflects what you've tried? We can only answer what you're asking and the answer here is your example code doesn't compile. Also, please post the definition of your `Data` class.

Comment: sorry for long aswer. Ahm topic closed, task is done ! Thank's anyway

Comment: @Kathelan: You can answer your own question here on Stack Overflow, that way it will help others in the future.